# preserving destination's data in Rsync

Tags: rsync

In RSYNC what ever changes are made at the source file are reflected at the source file are reflected at the destination file. But if we are doing some changes at both the source file and destination file and the doing RSYNC from source to destination the changes made in the destination file are gone and only changes of source is reflected. Is there any way to preserve the changes even at the destination while doing rsync. Any alternative to RSYNC will also help.

Comment: Did you try any of the answer suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for 2-way sync, so I'd recommend 
[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)

At the initial sync it generates a list displaying how the download/upload will be done, and which conflicts there are.

[Lipsync](https://github.com/philcryer/lipsync) is a linux dropbox clone which also also allows it and shows promise (there was a Lifehacker article about it some time ago).

Answer (score 0):

http://cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/status.html  Unison is no longer under active development as a research project.

I would be using dropbox to keep and track changes